# How to display search results like the iOS "Contacts" app

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am new iOS programming. I have tried to implement my app to look like the iOS Contacts app. But I have no idea how to implement what I desire. I want to get search results to look like the default iOS app.

Look what I tried so far:

[image: When i type something the dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation still <code>true</code>]

When I type something the dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation is still `true`.

Here is my expectation:

[image: Here is detail of my expectation]

I am wondering how this app shows results like this.

Here is how i declared `UISearchController`

```
lazy var searchController: UISearchController = ({

    let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    controller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    controller.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    controller.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
    controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true

    return controller

})()
```

Here is how i initialized `searchBar` to header section of `tableView`

```
let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    searchBar.delegate = self

    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

Here is function for delegate `UISearchResultsUpdating`

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    if let count = searchController.searchBar.text?.count {
        if count > 0  {

            filterArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            var a = [String]()
            a = [searchController.searchBar.text!]
            filterArray = a
            searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            tableView.reloadData()
        }else {
            searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
            filterArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            filterArray = array
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my `tableView` cell looks like

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searchController.isActive {
        return filterArray.count
    }else {
        return array.count
    }

}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)

    if searchController.isActive {
        cell.textLabel?.text = filterArray[indexPath.row]
    }else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]
    }


    return cell

}
```

Comment: You need to show some relevant code in your question (as text). Are you using a UISearchController?

Comment: Yes @rmaddy, i am using `UISearchController`

Comment: I have updated my questions ;)

Comment: You are not `filter`ing anything. You have to `filter` the main `array` to get only the items which contain the search text. And **never** check for empty string with `text.count > 0`. There is an optimized API: `!text.isEmpty`

Answer (score 0):

Try with these options:

```
let search = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            self.definesPresentationContext = true
            search.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            navigationItem.searchController = search
            navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
```

Try the code in my repo to see it working just tap a tableview item and it will segue to the second controller where you can see the searchbar and tap it to see if this is what you wanted

[github link](https://github.com/verebes1/searchbarhelp)

Answer (score 0):

```
    if navigationItem.searchController == nil {
        if searchController == nil {
            searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            searchController?.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
            searchController?.delegate = self
            searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = self
            searchController?.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            searchController?.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
        }
        self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    }
```

Use property **hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling** to make the search bar not scroll up, like the contacts app.